# Jest-Puppeteer Why warning "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: jestjs, integration-testing, jest-puppeteer

I finally got my first jest-puppeteer test to pass. - code below.
However I am getting the warning shown.

**Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.**

I looked at other questions here on stackoverflow and it looked like I should be using 'done' which I added into my test. However I am still getting same warning. Test still passes.

Why am I getting warning?

```
/**
 * @name Onplan Login
 * @desc Logs in and test for correct page title
 */
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const assert = require('assert');
let browser;
beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false,
        slowMo: 50
    });

})

describe('url should be correct"', () => {
    test('url is correct', async done => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://uat2.onplanapp.com/#/sheet/139');
        await page.waitFor(500);//was 500
        await page.waitFor('#inputEmail');
        await page.type('#inputEmail', 'mayank@onplan.co');
        await page.type('#inputPassword', '123456');
        await page.click('button');//Login
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await page.waitFor(100);//was 500
        // SELECT COMPANY ON NEXT PAGE
        await page.waitFor('#logn-screenv > form > div.row.logn-screenbody.pb-4.pt-3.px-2 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.css-1hwfws3.custom-scrollbar__value-container > div.css-151xaom-placeholder.custom-scrollbar__placeholder');
        await page.click('#logn-screenv > form > div.row.logn-screenbody.pb-4.pt-3.px-2 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.css-1hwfws3.custom-scrollbar__value-container > div.css-151xaom-placeholder.custom-scrollbar__placeholder');//Login

        // SELECT COMPANY 
        await page.waitFor(500);// was 1000

        // click dropdown to show list of companies
        await page.click('#react-select-2-option-2'); //Test company
        await page.waitFor(300);//was 1000
        await page.click('button[class="btn btn-block mt-3"]');
        //now we go to first page
        const url = await page.url();
        expect(url).toBe('https://uat2.onplanapp.com/#/');
        done();
    }, 20000);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding code below eliminated warning message.

```
afterAll(async done => {
    browser.close()

    done();
});
```